# What was the connection betwen robotic Cylons and human Cylons?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, cylon

I saw all seasons of Battlestar Galactica, but somewhere probably I missed a part.
The premise of the story was this:

1. Cylons (robot form) were created by humans (by the 12 colonies).
2. Cylons revolted against humans and a war began.
3. Then the Cylons go away and after 40 years they return with a "plan" in human form.

....

4. Then we have Earth, let’s say version 1, where the final 5 came from.
5. But the final 5 are 2000 years old.

So the final 5 came from Earth v1 and robotic Cylons were created by human colonies.

What is the connection (and evolution to human Cylons) between the robotic Cylons and the final 5 Cylons?

Who created the final 5 Cylons? Other humans? Or did I miss something?

Comment: basicly, x years ago humans made cylons, and the cylons evloved into humans(skinjobs) those cylons where the 13th colony. now the humans destroyed the 13th colony because they were afraid of the cylons. flash to present. humans make cylons again, cylons gain intelligence, revolt. meat these ancient cylons (the 5) along with the hybreds decide they need to kill all the humans before they kill them first. start bsg2004.

Comment: but this means humans knows that skinjobs cylons exists. or these were other humans?

Comment: “I saw all season of Battlestar galactica but somewhere probably I missed a part.” — I know the feeling!

Comment: 4 (or 6) seasons, depending on how you count them, 3 features, 3 web series... its a lot to take in

Comment: humanity had erased or forgoton about colony 13 and the erradication of the cylons there since it had been 1000s of years

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The literal connection in the series is that the final 5 came to the colonies and gave the cylons reincarnation in return for stopping the war.  This is not the theme they were intended to represent though.  They are the embodiment of the thesis of the show - that humans repeat their mistakes over, and over and over again, and the universe is in cycles.  They also represent the mistakes of humanity coming back, literally in this case, to haunt them.

## Who created the final 5?

No one.  They were born.  Their race of cylons, however, were created by humans thousands of years before the run of the show.

## Are the final 5 connected to the creation of the 7?

Kind of.  The modern cylons were well on their way to creating skin-jobs.  The final 5 just helped them along.

## And the Toasters?

Literally treated as pets by half the skinjobs, and as equals by the others.  Ostensibly, the toasters created the skin-jobs, but the skin-jobs had a 'divine blessing', and gained prominence.  It should be noted that most of the spacecraft fall into the toaster category, with the exception of the basestars, which are looked at as a kind of oracle.

## Timeline

This is what happens before the mini-series begins, and should provide some insight.

### Sometime earlier than 152,000 years before 2014

Humanity lives on the planet Kobol in 12 tribes.  They create cylons. The cylons revolted, and the planet kobol is abandoned.  Humanity goes to form the colonies, and the cylons go to earth 1.

### Sometime between 152,000 and 150,050 years ago

The cylons on Earth 1 create another race of cylons that revolt.  5 Cylons rediscover reincarnation, just as the bombs start to drop.  They travel back to the colonies, going at just below light speed, showing up at the colonies... we will get to that.  Sam also write "All along the watchtower."  [Dylan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Dylan) fails to give credit.

### 150,050 years ago (50 years before the show)

Greystone steals some technology and creates cylons again...out of his daughter.

### Circa 150,025 years ago

The Cylon revolt is well underway.  They are already developing skin jobs.  The final 5 arrive and convince the Cylons to end the war, and give them reincarnation.

### 150,000 years ago

Number 1 wipes the memories of the final 5, and starts another war with humanity.  the series begins.

Comment: so the final 5 were made by other humans (having the same trouble with cylons). the final 5 just for case meat and join the cylons created by the 12 colonies, right?

Comment: The final five were members of the 13th tribe of man (cylons) from the first exidus.  They left their planet (earth) after toasters decided to nuke the 13th tribe skinjobs.  They wanted to warn humanity not to make the mistake again, but it was too late, and they reached the colonies mid-war.

Comment: Should I just lay out the entire timeline?

Comment: ok that makes sense now, the phrase that I remember: "we travel at sub-light speed after leaving earth..." but still does not return to me because the 13th was destroyed 2000 years ago. A timeline should be best to explain

Comment: I found it here http://www.pinterest.com/pin/438045501227260067/, now I am decoding it :)

Comment: That image is actually... kinda... wrong?  Seven is named Danial, and we never see him.  His entire line is killed by the Ones.

Comment: @Tritium Kobol, holocaust, "flees" and "centurions" are spelt wrong. And I have no idea why it says that the armistice was in 1980?! Also we know that the centurions had an idea of the one true god long before the first war, so M is in the wrong place. What are "the lost episodes"?!?! There were rebel centurions but the graphic supposes otherwise. #29 is just nonsense, which is strange since #L gets it right. _(cont.)_

Comment: _(cont.)_ And the show ends up at New Earth, not Kobol; though that could be artistic licence to show the cyclical nature of things, that makes little sense given that the cycle was broken. Otherwise, it's very accurate.

Comment: The image was created before Daybreak aired

Comment: Let's not forget, the robotic Cylon had inhibiter chips installed to prevent free will.

Comment: Let's mot forget that the concept of the Five wasn't written into the storyline until the writers realised it was a growing thing in viewers.